# How to remove elements in static array effectively in C

Tags: c

In C programming, suppose we have an array as: `A[8] = {3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 9, 10, 1}`, how to modify those items by index range? For instance, to "remove" elements from index 3 to 6, since we have static array, after handling, we expect: `A[8] = {3, 5, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}`.

concerning dealing with one element at specified index:

```
for(i= index; i< size - 1; i++)
{
    A[i] = A[i+ 1];
}
size = size - 1
```

What's the best solution to this problem, suppose the array size can be very large.

Comment: You can't remove elements from an array. What you are doing is setting them to zero.

Comment: It depends on what you are doing, you may need to look into `realloc`...

Comment: @Joshpbarron In a static array?

Comment: I think question is ok. It's fine if you want to expect zero, although it can cause a problem. In your code you can interpret 0 as deleted element, but it's probable that in some function you forget to check this or will expect zero to be a normal value. Static arrays generally are not good for this. It's better to use vectors or lists and I would advice you to stick to those.

Comment: From the question, I don't think you can say it is static. The poster seems to think setting it to 0 is removing. Is it actually static?

Comment: Have a look at [`memmove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) and [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset).

Comment: memove and memset won't do well for static tables

Comment: Try [`memset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/), but if your array is made from `int` elements, then it will be not much faster than `for(;;)`

Comment: memove is for copying memory not for deleting items. Memset is more accurate to the problem, but still it's the same approach as setting values to 0

Comment: @juanchopanza said it correct , in case of static array you are not deleting , just u are memsetting it with zero , not possible with static , u must use dynamic

Comment: This is basic algorithm theory: arrays are good for quick access, but bad because removing and adding items is ineffective, particularly in the middle of an array. When picking the proper container for a certain task, you have to consider how frequently you need to add and remove items. Linked lists exist for the sole purpose of having a convenient way to add/remove items.

Comment: maybe the description is not well, yes, we can't remove items in static array, I modified the question to meet my purpose.

Comment: @all - he both moving, and setting, i.e., when "removing" an element, the higher elements are moving lower, and the highest address are/should be filled with 0 (though his alg is flawed in that respect).  So, memmove (not memcpy) to move elements down, then memset to clear highest slots.  Memset may be overkill, just keep track of size and clear element in the last slot after delete.

Comment: I don't see why this question needs to be down-voted. Simple, nicely put, nor the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an array, copy is all you can do.  You can copy element by element.  Or you can use memmove which permits overlapping memory space (memcpy is not safe for overlapping copies). memmove is more efficient than a loop (though optimizing compilers may solve that). You can use either method to copy to a temporary space, or to copy/move in place.  In all cases, you must makes sure your vacated cell is cleared.

```
        // an example that assumes you have valid index and size
        memmove(&A[index], &A[index+1], size-(index+1));
        A[--size] = 0;
```

The Big(O) is still N (linear with respect to size).  With very large arrays, the cost to delete goes up.  If unacceptable, you would need a different data structure.

So, consider all your requirements which include cost of inserting, cost of finding/changing, and cost of deleting elements.  Choose your data structure to match your requirements.  When the data set is small or there are relatively few transactions, the performance differences may not matter to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

One way to remove elements from array will be to create another array.
And then copy elements from (start, left) and (right, end) in second array.
Here (left,right) are indices of subarray which you want to remove.

Another way will be to override elements instead of creating another array.
If you need to maintain order then care needs to be taken while overriding.
else simple copy (right-left) elements from end of array (you need to set these elements to zero) and put it from left..right.

Answer (score 1):

Though `memset`, `memcpy`, `memmove` are options to you, if you want to implememnt something of your own, it could be something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_ARRAY_INDEX    10

static int array[10] = {1,5,1,4,8,9,6,3,7,2};

int Pull(int *arr, int from, int to, int count)
{
    int iter = 0;

    if((from<0) || (to<0))
        return 0;
    if((from>MAX_ARRAY_INDEX) || (to>MAX_ARRAY_INDEX))
        return 0;

    for(iter = 0; iter < count ; iter++,from++,to++)
    {
        arr[to] = arr[from];
        arr[from] = 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d,", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    if(Pull(array, 6, 2, 3));
        printf("\nIndexes pulled!");
    else
        //Error handling, the next part of the code can be vomited?

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d,", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    Pull(array, 9, 7, 2);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d,", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Though with this code you need to take care of pulling the indexes completely. May be instead of using a `count` check in `for()` loop, you could do it till the `MAX_ARRAY_INDEX` ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use memcpy and memset for readability, but also because they are get optimized well by the compiler.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void array_print (const int* arr, size_t size)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

void array_remove (int* arr, size_t size, size_t index, size_t rem_size)
{
  int* begin = arr+index;                        // beginning of segment to remove
  int* end   = arr+index+rem_size;               // end of segment to remove
  size_t trail_size = size-index-rem_size;       // size of the trailing items after segment

  memcpy(begin,                                  // move data to beginning
         end,                                    // from end of segment
         trail_size*sizeof(int));

  memset(begin+trail_size,                       // from the new end of the array
         0,                                      // set everything to zero
         rem_size*sizeof(int));
}

int main (void)
{
  int array [8] = {3, 5, 6, 8, 2, 9, 10, 1};
  const int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);

  array_print(array, size);
  array_remove(array, size, 3, 4); // from index 3, remove 4 items
  array_print(array, size);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant remove from an array unless it is dynamically initialized.

> Google Linked Lists.

Best case scenario would be to substitute to get the answer. such as

```
int indexStart = 3;
int indexEnd= 6;
for(int i=indexStart; i<A.length;i++){
    if(indexEnd<A.length) 
      A[i]=A[indexEnd+1];
    else
      A[i]=0;
    indexEnd++;
}
```